# Location of Manage Google Apps organization users option and menu

Tags: google-workspace

Where do I find the option or menu to manage users in my Google Apps organization?

I can't find it, looked everywhere in the Gmail site options. I found "Manage this domain" menu, but it only shows me my end user options and no sign of the Admin console to add/edit my custom Google Apps domain users.

Am I blind? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the help documents: [Turn services on/off for certain users](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182442&topic=14576&ctx=topic)

**Log in to the Google Apps administrator control panel.
The URL is https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/primary-domain-name, where primary-domain-name is the domain name you used to sign up for Google Apps.**

My problem is that I have two differnt domains associated with my account and I have to go though the original one

Comment: Hmm, even the direct link wouldn't show me the right page in Chrome (my default browser). So I tried in IE and it worked - I got to the Admin console! Thanks for your help!